# GNU Emacs on Windows: unable to apply init file changes and to type tilde symbol

Tags: windows, emacs

**Problem 1**

I'm trying to customize my Emacs with the init file.

I found the correct place of my init file, and tried to write some code in it to change Emacs behavior.

Following the document examples, I wrote the following line of code

```
(setq fill-column 20)
```

Then saved the file. But when I start Emacs, the fill-column variable is still set to 70 as default. If I modify that variable on the fly, Emacs accepts the new value instead as normal.

I wonder if I'm missing something about the init file. Should I explicit tell Emacs to load it? Should I include other code statements to make it applying the changes?

**Problem 2**

To refer to your HOME directory in Emacs, you have to use the tilde symbol at the beginning of the path, for example when you want to find your init file position via Emacs, like this

```
~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

But how is it possible to type such a character if it's not present on my keyboard and ALT codes aren't working (because ALT followed by numbers is being treated as a command input)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Is your init file actually executed? Here's how you find out: Put something syntactically incorrect into it. If emacs complains on startup, it's executing the file - otherwise the problem is that you and emacs disagree about where your home directory is.

(2) Every Windows keyboard layout I know of has a binding for ~ - it may be on an AltGr combination, on a dead key etc., but it's always there. The Windows system control panel can help you verify and select your keyoard layout. But if you really don't have a binding for ~, you can always type

```
<C-q> 1 7 6 / . e m a c s
```

in emacs instead (176 is the octal for 126, the ASCII code of ~).

Comment: Nice tip, I tried writing a bunch of random symbols and Emacs complain on startup, stating there was a problem loading the init file (with the correct path) so it is loading... but where is the problem then? The lambda tip is working! Thanks for that!

Comment: When your fill-column setting isn't repected, it's usually because you set it globally, and it gets reset by some mode-specific initialization that you're not aware of using. For instance, for C programming I use 
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 75)
)

That way *my* initialization is run after any code that the cc-mode maintainers have registered, and I get my favorite settings and not theirs.

Comment: Understood, I tried to set a custom variable name and value and effectively Emacs return the correct value for that variable! Must be like you said, but your code doesn't work for me... I will study the language more to find a way around, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation for `fill-column` clearly says, it is normally buffer-local, i.e. it gets set to a buffer-specific value when you create a new buffer.  You are setting the fill-column of the buffer which is active when your `.emacs` executes, but that is a temporary buffer which ceases to exist before you get to inspect it.

To achieve what (I think) you want, you'd use `(setq-default fill-column 20)` ... although I would advise against this in the general case.  (Probably you would want to have the very narrow definition only for a particular set of modes; you would set this variable for these buffers using the corresponding mode hook, or using the advise facility.)

Your other question got answered already so I will be ignoring that.  Please don't post multiple questions in the same thread.

Comment: `setq-default` did the trick. Actually I don't want to override anything about Emacs this way, as I'm aware of modes. But now I'm sure that everything works ok and I can focus more on the study of the language to enhance Emacs functionalities! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: If you cannot accept my answer as correct (see, this is one of the issues with multiple questions in a single posting), could you please at least upvote by clicking on the up-arrow. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, didn't think about the multiple question issue!